# mixing multi select and single select in one list of ajax results

Tags: gui-design, mobile, user-behavior, search, filter

I'm designing a mobile app (android + ios)

I'd like to have a page where you can type in a search bar, and get a list of (ajax) results you can choose from.

the results are a name, with either - `team` or `player` tag

if you select `team` - you can then go to second page, preferably, without pressing `next` button.

if you select `player` - you have the option to select others (up to 6) or not - keep only one, and then move to second page.

I had few UI options in mind (but none satisfies me) :

1. pressing `team` will move immediately to page2, pressing player will enable `next` button, and you can select more or press next.
2. any select moves to page2 -> page2 shows a list of selected subjects, if it's a team - you can't change it (besides `back`), if player - you press `more` and a popup (or something else? - move back?) opens so you can select more
3. page1 is divided to `team` and `player` search, losing the cool multi-search option
4. in result list - if you select `player` or `team` it will be marked with `V`, if you select another `player` - you'll have two `V`s, if you select a team - the `V` will change to that. (might be confusing, so some explanation text is possible. also I can divide to results to two sections)
5. result list is divided to two section - pressing a `player` or `team` will move to page2. above `players` part, a text will say `"long press for multiselect"`. long press will clear the search bar, and somewhere show all previously selected players with `done` button. (Q: is long press common method for IOS ? )

Would appreciate to hear any idea

Comment: If you have some options already, please add them, right now this question is too broad

Comment: right. edited..

Comment: Would it make sense to offer the choice before the search is initiated? E.g. a droplist or radio control where the user selects either "team" or "player", then inputs the search term.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You talk about 'going to a second page'. What is the goal here (both business and the user)? 

You are mixing search and selection as well: It sounds like I can select a single team entity or a player entity which you can multiselect (in effect grouping into an ad hoc 'team'). If we know the apps goal here, it can provide some clues to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are merging two separate things, and you shouldn't.

Either the user wants to pick a team, or they want to pick six players - so just ask them which. Trying to merge this will just demand extra thought from the user, and give them opportunities to get it wrong (e.g. trying to pick a few players, and then a team).

Also, don't immediately go to another page once they have made a selection - because they might want to change it.

Instead, once they have made a selection, either enable a previously disabled button that will take them to a second page, or display the new information on the same page, below their selection.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough - normal behavior is 1 `player` or 1 `team`. We allow having more than 1 `player` as an extra-option .    

about your second feedback - selecting without approving it will spare me a button - if the user wants, he can press back (or i'll add `change` button in page2), the selected subject will be present there any  way

Answer (score 0):

You can add a drop-down for your search bar with suggestions. In that box, you can also add a message that let the user know what advantages has if he choose an option from the select.

If he doesn't want to choose at that point anything, display all the results after he submits the form and keep the search bar on top, with your "cool multi-select option".

If he chooses "team", display the filtered results.

If he chooses "player", display the multi-select. It is not unusual to display features conditioned by a previous filter.

Of course, you can let the user choose between simple and advanced search at the beginning.